# Function returns -nan

Tags: c++, nan

I have this code. Why does it produce `-nan` upon returning a value in main program?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace::std;

float f(float x)
{
    float result = -5 * x * x - 2 * x + 1;
    return powf(result, (float)1/(float)3);
}
int main()
{
    cout<<f(-1)<<endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This confuses me. As I far as I know, I use suitable data type.

Comment: `-5 * x * x - 2 * x + 1` is negative for `-1`

Comment: `If the base is finite negative and the exponent is finite but not an integer value, it causes a domain error.` It says right on the reference page.

Comment: @slawekwin: Actually, negative numbers do have odd roots (e.g., cube root of -27 is -3). It's only even roots of negative numbers that require imaginary numbers.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Actually all roots require imaginary numbers: cubic root has 2 imaginary results and 1 real.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: It's true that there are complex roots as well (just as there are complex roots of positive numbers), but there are purely real odd roots of negative numbers. So no, not all roots *require* imaginary numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the desired functionality is not available with `std::pow`. Instead you could use `std::cbrt` or simply do like so:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>

using namespace::std;

float f(float x)
{
    float result = -5 * x * x - 2 * x + 1;
    float intermediate = powf(std::abs(result),(float)1/(float)3);
    if (std::signbit(result))
        return -intermediate; // Negate if 'result' is negative
    return intermediate;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<f(-1)<<endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

You can also just use one of the overloads of `std::pow` instead of `powf`

```
#include<iostream> // std::cout, std::endl
#include<cstdio>   // getchar
#include<cmath>    // std::pow, std::abs, std::signbit

float f(float x)
{
    float result = -5.0f * x * x - 2.0f * x + 1.0f;
    float intermediate = std::pow(std::abs(result),1.0f/3.0f);
    if (std::signbit(result))
        return -intermediate; // Negate if 'result' is negative
    return intermediate;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f(-1) << std::endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Online [here](http://ideone.com/5YiLoA)

Answer (score 7):

When you call your function with negative one the base is equal to -2 and the exponent is 1/3 (non-integer).

According to the specification for [powf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow):

> pow(base, exponent) returns NaN and raises FE_INVALID if base is finite and negative and exponent is finite and non-integer.

Which explains why your function is returning NaN.

If you're trying to calculuate the cubic root I suggest you use [cbrt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cbrt) instead.

Answer (score 1):

[cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/nan-function/) reference say:

> The NaN values are used to identify undefined or non-representable
>   values for floating-point elements, such as the square root of
>   negative numbers or the result of 0/0.
>
> The argument can be used by library implementations to distinguish
>   different NaN values in a implementation-specific manner.